# Server selection timed out after 30000 ms {"name":"MongooseTimeoutError","reason":{"name":"MongoNetworkError"}}

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod, mongodb-atlas

**Context**

I'm using **GCP**, more specifically **GKE** to deploy my app in container/pod. The app I'm trying to deploy is in node js (express js). This app connects to **MongoDB Atlas** *(free tier M0)*.

**No issue when running the project locally.** It connects to the database and I can add/remove documents without any problems.

I allowed my MongoDB Atlas Cluster to get access by anyone (0.0.0.0/0) to make it easier debugging.

When I deploy my project with my CI/CD Deploy to GKE every thing goes smooth.

**Problem**

Things starts to get tricky once I've deployed my project. I get a **CrashLoopBackOff**. It keeps crashing after checking the logs here is what I've found:

`error: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms {"name":"MongooseTimeoutError","reason":{"name":"MongoNetworkError"}}`

**Leads**

I believe the issue is that **my pod can't connect to MongoDB Atlas** through its regular port 27017 sending me a timeout error.

Here is what I've tried:

- Adding in my VPC Network in GCP a new **firewall rule**: 
  `gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-mongodb --allow tcp:27017`
- Adding in my deployment.yml the following key/value: `dnsPolicy: Default`

**Conclusion**

After spending hours on this problem, I still didn't find any solutions and I'm running out of ideas.
FYI, I'm new to GCP and to Kubernetes so I might be missing something big here but not sure what.

If some kind person end up on that post and knows the answer I would be glad if he/she could help me out here.

Have a good one.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

If you think the network policy has been set properly with GCP firewall rules, let's work out it in kubernetes step by step.

1. check if you can connect to mongodb Atlas from the containers themselves.

```
kubectl exec <node_app_pod> --command -- curl <mongo_url>:27017
```

2. check the network policy in kubernetes. To make it simplified, allow all egress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-all
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  egress:
  - {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

If you want to set port 27017 only, you can adjust with this document :

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/

Let me know if it is better now.

Comment: thank you very much for you answer. I can't even get access to the pod, I keep getting ```Error from server (NotFound): pods <POD_ID> not found``` (maybe because it keeps crashing and it's never getting really up).
Otherwise for the second part, I haven't set any NetworkPolicy before so I've added your yml but unfortunately it didn't change anything. I still get the same error (title of my question).
Also not sure if I really set up properly the network policy in GCP...

Comment: No, not pod id, should be `pod name`, the name when you run `kubectl get pods`

Comment: Well that's the thing when I run ```kubectl get pods``` I get ```No resources found.``` I think it's because containers keep crashing so I can't even get access to them since they're not up and running...

Comment: can you start another pod and run the same curl command? such as `kuberctl run alpine --image alpine --generator=run-pod/v1 --command -- sleep 5000` . then you can `exec` to it and run curl command (maybe you need `apk add --update curl` first)

Comment: Thanks for your help @BMW. I managed to start an alpine pod. I did apply the network policy you've provided. Once I've tried the curl here is the response I have: ```curl: (52) Empty reply from server```. I think I might still have a connection problem here. What do you think?

Comment: Seems my problem was about having namespace involved into my kubernetes yaml files. Idk what was missing but getting rid of it, folding back to namespace "default", gave my pod the ability to communicate with my database and other external APIs.